# Need to create SVN user and provide access to SVN application

Tags: tortoisesvn

We have Linux based SVN application server on which I need to create new user and provide it application access.

It should be access using SVN Tortoise tool which we used to copy data on server.

Basically we need to copy data on SVN server using SVN Tortoise tool.

Please help here, thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need to add the new Linux user account to the dev group, done and done.

Comment: Without any detail on the configuration or setup, it's impossible to answer this question. SVN can for instance be transported over HTTP(S) or SSH, or it's own svn protocol. The setup may be a `.htaccess` file, or it may be unix user accounts...